# Using a variable in every view controller how?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

As the title says I need to use same variable in different viewcontllers.

Until this day when I want to use a variable in different viewcontllers I send that specific variable via segues but I don't think that is a good way it requires program to carry variables from one point to another and if there are 5 view controllers this can be messy.

When I search the internet I always found codes about sending variables from one to another by segues and I have read something about global variables but I am not sure that is the one.

Example:(3 view controller program)

User opens the app and at the first viewcontller clicks ''3'' button ( or 1-2-3-4-5) the int x variable become x=3.Later he choses to go on.

Second view controller writes on screen x+x user clicks to 3 viewcontroller.(code is written inside)

Third view controller writes on screen x*x user clicks to 3 view controller.(code is written inside)

As you can see I have used that x variable in different view controllers and please remember I don't want to transfer variables between them so any ideas for that and is this kind of a thing possible.

My Guess using pointers or taking some space in memory my malloc and pointing it from anotherviewcontroller might work.

Answer:As stated in answer below there are two ways this one is suitable for me.

1 view controller

```
int x =5;

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[defaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:x] forKey:@"keyForTheValue"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

2 view controller

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
int y = [[defaults objectForKey:@"keyForTheValue"] intValue];
intyazi.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d",  y];
```

Comment: Singletons could be your friend: http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/singleton-classes/

Comment: Do you have any kind of data model at your app that is separate from view controllers ?

Comment: Nope all I want is to share a simple int variable of course for now if I can learn a efficient way to do this then I will choose to share images or sounds as well.About singleton so if I wrote it like that can I acsess it from every where ?

Comment: Yes. Singletons ensure, that there is only one instance existing. And you can access this instance from everywhere. If the int value needs to be persistent you could also use NSUSerDefaults and store it there.

Comment: I think you need to read up on the Model-View-Controller pattern. It sounds like you're trying to use your VCs as your models, and passing model-like data in between your VCs. You should have a backing model that your VCs all draw from to show their data, which I believe is what some people were getting at with the "use a singleton" comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to avoid passing the variable from ViewController to ViewController.

*But keep in mind, that in some cases it's better to pass it.*

### Singleton Datacontainer

One way would be using a Singleton Datacontainer:

Header (Threadsafe implementation):

```
#import <foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyManager : NSObject {
    NSInteger *someProperty;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSInteger *someProperty;

+ (id)sharedManager;

@end
```

Implementation:

```
#import "MyManager.h"

@implementation MyManager

@synthesize someProperty;

#pragma mark Singleton Methods

+ (id)sharedManager {
    static MyManager *sharedMyManager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedMyManager = [[self alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedMyManager;
}

- (id)init {
  if (self = [super init]) {
      // Default value
      someProperty = @0;
  }
  return self;
}

@end
```

### NSUserDefaults

Or you could use NSUserDefaults. Which does store the value persistent in the user directory and is also available on the next startup.

Storing a value:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[defaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:yourIntValue] forKey:@"keyForTheValue"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

Loading the value:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
int yourIntValue = [[defaults objectForKey:@"keyForTheValue"] intValue];
```

Comment: Storing the value seems like a good option I will try that and write the results.

Comment: where should I wrote the int variable and how can I take it by using NsUserDefult ?

Comment: You can only store objects in NSUserDefaults. Just wrap it into a NSNumber or a NSInteger. I have changed the above example for your use case having a primitive int.

Comment: lots and lots errors I am getting trying to work out now I thing the code structure is little bit different in NSInteger : (

Comment: Look at the code example. I changed it to using a NSNumber. Should work with that.

Comment: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException I get this error :S

Comment: I have posted my code in question which receives the error I mention above

Comment: Your error lies somewhere else. I copied this piece of code and it worked.. Do you also get the error when you remove the line with the assignment of intyazi?

Comment: yeah but you are also correct somehow my program got messy I am trying to sort it out